# Javascript - prompt + loop on array - how to ask to only re-response the wrongly answered question and not all the loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

**Objectives :**

1. to have the user type the shown words in the input fields.
2. to check if the typed word are exact copy of the ones that were asked.
3. if yes, then go on to the next one
4. if no, then ask to type again the wrongly typed word

All the words are included in an array.

**What works so far :**

objectives 1 to 3 work great !

**What doesn't work :**

Objective 4 partially works. The problem is that it restarts the whole loop instead of keeping track of the progress so far and only restart from the wrongly answered question.

**The code :**

```
 wordList = ["Cachalot", "Pétunia", "Serviette"]
 score = 0
  for (let i=0; i<wordList.length; i++){
        let typedWord = prompt("Veuillez recopier le mot suivant : " + wordList[i])
        if(typedWord===wordList[i]){
            score+=1
            console.log(score)
        } else{
            console.log ("merci de recommencer")
            typeSmart()
        }

    }
}typeSmart()
```

I know calling the function is due to start the whole process again. But I'm a bit clueless as how to do otherwise. should I use a *while* instead or in complement of the current *for* loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a `while` loop instead. As you don't know how many times you're going to be asking for the word (ie: looping), a `while` loop is more appropriate. `for` loops are typically better for when you know the number of times in advance you need to loop, which isn't the case here.

When the user gets the word correct, you can advance the index of the current word you're looking at (in the below snippet I've called that `currentWordIdx`). Also, make sure you declare your variables with `let` or `const` (`var` is also an option but not preferred), otherwise they become global variables and may impact other parts of your code outside of your function unintentionally:

```js
function typeSmart() {
  const wordList = ["Cachalot", "Pétunia", "Serviette"];
  let score = 0;
  let currentWordIdx = 0;
  while(currentWordIdx < wordList.length) {
    const currentWord = wordList[currentWordIdx];
    const typedWord = prompt("Veuillez recopier le mot suivant : " + currentWord);
    if (typedWord === currentWord) {
      score += 1;
      currentWordIdx++; // advance to the next word
      console.log(score);
    } else {
      console.log("merci de recommencer");
    }
  }
}
typeSmart();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your help. A quick question though : why did you set both curentWord and typedWord variable as const and not let ? We know their value is going to change, no ?

Comment: @Elradsoldier Hey, each iteration of your loop creates _new_ `currentWord ` and `typedWord` variables. So since you're not actually reassigning them (ie: you don't do `currentWord = ...` or  `typedWord = ...`) further down in the code, then it's safe to keep them as `const` (as we don't intend to reassign them, setting them as `const` highlights that intent)

Comment: Oh yeah... I didn't realise what was actually coding. Thank you for all the precisions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop to repeat the input comparison until the values match. And by using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate over the word list, you can avoid dealing with indexes entirely.

```js
function typeSmart() {
  const wordList = ["Cachalot", "Pétunia", "Serviette"];
  let score = 0;
  for (const word of wordList) {
    const message = `Veuillez recopier le mot suivant : ${word}`;
    while (prompt(message) !== word) {
      console.log("merci de recommencer");
    }
    score += 1;
    console.log(score);
  }
}

typeSmart();
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, it's indeed a clean and concise solution :-)

Comment: Nice thinking, this is much cleaner than maintaining an index.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `--i;` in your `else` statement. This will keep the value of `i` for the `for` loop the same, untill the user enters the correct answer. So it will keep prompting the same prompt, until the user enters rhe correct answer, which serves your purpose.

```
wordList = ["Cachalot", "Pétunia", "Serviette"]
 score = 0
  for (let i=0; i<wordList.length; i++){
        let typedWord = prompt("Veuillez recopier le mot suivant : " + wordList[i])
        if(typedWord===wordList[i]){
            score+=1
            console.log(score)
        } else{
            console.log ("merci de recommencer")
            --i;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your answer did the job with the fewer modification possible, thanks.